# What's the easiest way to print seleced key values from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains several keys and values, ie:

```
d = {'1' : "whatever", '2' : "something", '3' : "other", '4' : "more" ...etc}
```

I would like to quickly print selected values from that code, for example  values of following keys: 1,3,20,23,45,46 etc.

I know I can print value by value:

```
print d['1'] + d['3'] +d['20'] + d['23'] + d['45'] + d['46']
```

but that'll take to long to type and the number sequence is visually unclear. What would be the simplest way to print out selected values, while keeping the sequence visualy easy to read (ideally something like `print d['1','3','20','23','45','46']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution is the easiest to understand:

```
keys_to_print = ['1', '3', '20', '23', '45', '46']
for key in keys_to_print:
    print d[key] + ' ',
```

This just loops through all of the keys whose values you want to print.

Comment: You might want to do d.get(key, None) to avoid any key errors

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, but this answer seemed the simplest and worked like a charm. Thanks laurencevs!

Comment: @skzryzg, d.get would return None by default

Answer (score 2):

You could combine [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
map(d.get, ['1', '3', '20', '23', '45', '46'])
```

This will give you a list of the corresponding values, such as:

```
['whatever', 'other', 'something', 'more']
```

You could print them with:

```
print ' '.join(map(d.get, ['1', '3', '20', '23', '45', '46']))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> keys = ['1', '3', '4', '2']
>>> print ' '.join(itemgetter(*keys)(d))
whatever other more something
>>> print ' '.join(itemgetter('1', '3', '4', '2')(d)) #without a `keys` variable.
whatever other more something
```

Using `str.join` with a generator expression:

```
>>> print ' '.join(d[k] for k in keys)
whatever other more something
```

If you're using Python 3 or willing to import print function in Python 2:

```
>>> print(*itemgetter(*keys)(d), sep=' ')
whatever other more something
>>> print(*itemgetter('1', '3', '4', '2')(d), sep=' ')
whatever other more something
>>> print(*(d[k] for k in keys), sep=' ')
whatever other more something
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has proposed the obvious:

```
d = {'1' : "whatever", '2' : "something", '3' : "other", '4' : "more",
     '20': 'vingt', '23': 'vingt-trois', '45':'quarante-cinq', '46':'quarante-six' }
keys_to_print = ['1', '3', '20', '23', '45', '46']

print ' '.join([d[key] for key in keys_to_print])
```

Producing:

```
whatever other vingt vingt-trois quarante-cinq quarante-six
```

Comment: I would use  `' '.join([d[key] for key in keys_to_print])`

Comment: @Padraic What would be the benefit ?

Comment: using `' '.join([d[key] for key in keys_to_print])` is more efficient

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you for your explanation. Of course, you're right... Fixed!

Comment: May I ask why adding 2 brackets is more efficient?

Comment: @user3210787 with `[]` you create a list whose values are defined at list creation. Without, you create a _generator_. Simply said, there will be a function call each time you retrieve a value.